# Kafka 0.10.1.1 Consumer re balancing resetting offset for partition to earliest offset

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration

ConsumerCoordinator is going into cyclic loop when reassinging a reovked partition.

CC is receiving committed offset as 78, however it discards this offset stating it is stale fetch and then assigning offset to earliest offset which is 83.

Kafka Cluster (kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0) and consumer application are running on CentOS 7.4.

Consumer application is configured with below version

```
org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:0.10.1.1
org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:2.1.0.RELEASE
org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:1.1.3.RELEASE
```

Consumer logs:

```
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [AbstractCoordinator.java:711] Attempt to heart beat failed for group myCGroup since member id is not valid.
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator [ConsumerCoordinator.java:333] Revoking previously assigned partitions  [my-topic-0] for group myCGroup
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1 [AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:242] partitions revoked:[my-topic-0]
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [AbstractCoordinator.java:381] (Re-)joining group myCGroup
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [AbstractCoordinator.java:390] Sending JoinGroup ({group_id=myCGroup,session_timeout=10000,rebalance_timeout=300000,member_id=,protocol_type=consumer,group_protocols=[{protocol_name=range,protocol_metadata=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=41 cap=41]}]}) to coordinator omscore4101p.prod.ch4.s.com:9092 (id: 2147483636 rack: null)
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [AbstractCoordinator.java:406] Received successful join group response for group myCGroup: {error_code=0,generation_id=92,group_protocol=range,leader_id=consumer-1-c79a0997-0555-4f7a-abe5-59e1c33e6670,member_id=consumer-1-49dd3506-bb8c-4c87-9fa2-d27cd54488f1,members=[]}
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [AbstractCoordinator.java:460] Sending follower SyncGroup for group fs Group to coordinator omscore4101p.prod.ch4.s.com:9092 (id: 2147483636 rack: null): {group_id=myCGroup,generation_id=92,member_id=consumer-1-49dd3506-bb8c-4c87-9fa2-d27cd54488f1,group_assignment=[]}
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator [AbstractCoordinator.java:349] Successfully joined group myCGroup with generation 92
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator [ConsumerCoordinator.java:225] Setting newly assigned partitions [my-topic-0] for group myCGroup
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator [ConsumerCoordinator.java:708] Group myCGroup fetching committed offsets for partitions: [my-topic-0]
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher [Fetcher.java:220] Resetting offset for partition my-topic-0 to the committed offset 78
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator [ConsumerCoordinator.java:640] Group myCGroup committed offset 78 for partition my-topic-0
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1 [AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:247] partitions assigned:[my-topic-0]
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher [Fetcher.java:677] Discarding stale fetch response for partition my-topic-0 since its offset 83 does not match the expected offset 78
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher [Fetcher.java:714] Fetch offset 78 is out of range for partition my-topic-0, resetting offset
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher [Fetcher.java:340] Resetting offset for partition my-topic-0 to earliest offset.
[-kafka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.Fetcher [Fetcher.java:583] Fetched {timestamp=-1, offset=83} for partition my-topic-0
```

Out put for kafka-consumer-groups describe:

```
TOPIC     PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST        CLIENT-ID
my-topic  1          85              85              0          consumer-1-702fcd74-bd70-4172-b070-8c2d2ef6ca9f   /x.x.x.x    consumer-1
my-topic  0          78              83              5          consumer-1-49dd3506-bb8c-4c87-9fa2-d27cd54488f1   /x.x.x.x    consumer-1
my-topic  2          83              85              2          consumer-1-c79a0997-0555-4f7a-abe5-59e1c33e6670   /x.x.x.x    consumer-1
```

Questions:

- What configuration change will reduce this error? "Attempt to heart beat failed for group myCGroup since member id is not valid."
- How to instruct Fetcher to get the latest offset?
- What is the reason for stale offset? how to fix it?

Comment: This is probably not relevant to your question, but spring-kafka 1.1.x is no longer supported; you should upgrade to at least 1.3.8; the current version is 2.2.2. 1.3.x introduced a much simpler threading model thanks to KIP-62.

Comment: Thank you @Gary Russell. Noted. we will upgrade to 1.3.8. However what is the reason for heart beat failure? We don't observe these failures in test environment.

Comment: Before 1.3 we had a complicated threading model with 2 threads per listener and we attempted to prevent a rebalance by pausing the consumer when the listener was too slow, and resuming it when it caught up. This generally worked, so I don't know what happened in your case, but KIP-62 allowed us to get rid of the second thread and greatly simplify the listener container. Since we not longer support those versions, I can't spend time trying to figure out what happened in your case.